# makeFirstResponder won't compile

Tags: macos, swift

I have an array of buttons and an array of associated NSTextViews (embedded in NSScrollViews), all created programmatically.  All this in a program (a calendar) that compiles and works fine as far as it does.

However, I would like clicking a button to cause the associated text field to behave as if I had clicked directly in it (cursor and focus ring appear and it accepts text).  Right now, I have to click the button AND the text box before I begin entering text.

It appears that “makeFirstResponder” should do what I want, but it won’t compile as I am trying to do it.

Here is the relevant code:

(All in a single View Controller)

Global Declarations:

```
var arrayOfButtons:[NSButton] = []
var arrayOfFields: [NSTextView!] = []
var arrayOfWindows: [NSScrollView!] = []
```

Creation of array of fields:

```
var i = 0

var myLocalText: NSTextView! = NSTextView(…
    var myLocalWindow: NSScrollView! = NSScrollView(…

        for i = 0; i <= 6; i++ {

            var myLocalText: NSTextView! = NSTextView(…
            var myLocalWindow: NSScrollView! = NSScrollView(…

            view.addSubview(myLocalWindow)

            myLocalWindow.hasVerticalScroller = false
            myLocalWindow.focusRingType = NSFocusRingType(rawValue: UInt(2))!  // I didn’t get a focus ring until I did this
            myLocalWindow.addSubview(myLocalText)
            myLocalWindow.documentView = myLocalText

            myLocalText.editable = true
            myLocalText.selectable = true
            myLocalText.verticallyResizable = true

            self.arrayOfFields.append(myLocalText)

        }
```

Routine that responds to clicking a button:

```
…

view.makeFirstResponder(arrayOfFields[tag])  // THIS IS THE SUBJECT OF MY QUESTION

// IT GIVES A COMPILER ERROR AS FOLLOWS: “Cannot invoke ‘makeFirstResponder’ with an argument list of type ’NSTextView’”
// as far as I can tell from the documentation, makeFirstResponder should accept an argument type of NSResponder, and NSTextView should inherit from that
```

Comment: Try to keep the unnecessary introductory and closing fluff out of your questions, please.

Comment: Seriously? Why do I think if I had left that out somebody else would have complained 'not enough information' or 'what are you trying to do?'  :-)

Comment: Actually *I* probably would have said that. :))))

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X, `makeFirstResponder` is an NSWindow method, not an NSView method.

Comment: "Look into" what? That's just the way it is. There is nothing to "look into", except maybe the documentation, which would have told you this without wasting Stack Overflow bandwidth.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you smiled at my first response anyway :-)

Comment: How about "try this"?  I did and it works (yeah, you know that).  So the compiler error was misleading - thank goodness that never usually happens!

Comment: This is an absolutely classic case of how Swift's error messages are misleading. Instead of saying that you can't send `makeFirstResponder` to an NSView at all, it tells you there is something wrong with the parameter list. If you have time, file a bug with Apple; this style of error message causes a lot of unnecessary trouble, and you have a good use case illustrating this fact.